# How to attach an existing View to a controller action?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I attach an existing View to an Action?
I mean, I've already attached this very View to an Action, but what I want is to attach to a second Action.

Example:
I've an Action named Index and a View, same name, attached to it, right click, add view..., but now, how to attach to a second one? Suppose an Action called Index2, how to achieve this?

Here's the code:

```
//this Action has Index View attached
public ActionResult Index(int? EntryId)
{
   Entry entry = Entry.GetNext(EntryId);

   return View(entry);
}

//I want this view Attached to the Index view...
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Rewind(Entry entry)//...so the model will not be null
{
   //Code here

   return View(entry);
}
```

I googled it and cant find an proper answer...
It's possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot "attach" actions to views but you can define what view you want be returned by an action method by using `Controller.View` Method

```
public ActionResult MyView() {
    return View(); //this will return MyView.cshtml
}
public ActionResult TestJsonContent() {
    return View("anotherView");
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460331%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

Comment: When I right click on Action the context menu shows me the Add View option, that's ok. So I cant Add this same View to another Action?

Comment: you can manually add a new view to your project then return it using the code above

Comment: I dont want to add a new View, I want to reuse an existing View with another Action named differently...

Comment: fine just use the return view overload
return View("anyViewYouWant");

Comment: you have to pass the model too:  

return View("/Views/yAnotherView.cshtml", yourModel);

Answer (score 4):

Does this help? You can use the overload of View to specify a different view:

```
 public class TestController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Test/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Hello I'm Mr. Index";

        return View();
    }


    //
    // GET: /Test/Index2
    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Hello I'm not Mr. Index, but I get that a lot";

        return View("Index");
    }


}
```

Here is the View (Index.cshtml):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>@ViewBag.Message</p>
```

Comment: In your example it would be return View("Index", entry);

Comment: Actually, not... I need to pass the model as argument to the action.

Comment: I meant you can replace the line under `//Code here`, `return View(entry);` in your code with `return View("Index", entry);`